# Can someone please assit me with the output of this function

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<html>
<script>
function zero ( zeroArray ){
        console.log('ZERO ARRAY ' + zeroArray)
        if(zeroArray !== undefined){
            let fixed = parseInt(zeroArray).toFixed(1)
            console.log('REPLACE '+ fixed.replace(".", ""))
            return fixed.replace(".", "")
        }
        return zeroArray
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

- the function appends a 0 when there is an undefined number after the input ie 4 will return 40
- say the input is 4.4, it needs to return 44 and at the moment it returns 40, or say 3.5 should return 35 which returns 30
- thanks for any help provided

Comment: looks like you just want to multiply by 10.

Comment: @pilchard I think you right but how do i identify a decimal number as an input

Comment: What's the exact purpose of that function? It's quite odd to call a String value `zeroArray`

Comment: Your HTML code is not valid. A `script` tag is not permitted in a `html` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function zero(zeroArray) {
    if (zeroArray !== undefined) {
        let fixed = zeroArray * 10;
        return fixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt, rounds it to an integer. Use parseFloat.

Example

```
parseFloat('10.5').toFixed(1).replace('.','');  // output "105"
```

Comment: how do I identify the decimal number in the input ie if(decimal ) then pasefloat

Comment: Really need to know what your function needs to do. Currently based on your description @Benreaby, if input is `10`, you want to append a trailing zero to the final output, which is also handled by using parseFloat. What is the reason to _detect_ a decimal?